# Nothing showing up on my canvas after I import a js file

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I'm trying to make a javascript game but nothing is showing up on my html canvas after I imported a js file(car.js), everything was showing up before I imported *car.js*. I currently have a folder called cargame and it includes 3 files, *car.js*, *firstgame.html* and *index.js*. I'm providing the contents of the files below.

**firstgame.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Web Page Design</title>

<style>
#gamescreen{
        border: 1px solid black;
}
#bgcolor{
    background-color: #b4b4b4;
}
</style>

</head>
<body id="bgcolor">
    <div align = "center" style="margin-top: 5%"><canvas id = "gamescreen" width = "500px" height = "600px"></canvas></div>

    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**index.js**

```
import car from "./car";


let canvas = document.getElementById("gamescreen");
let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');


const GAME_WIDTH = 500;
const GAME_HEIGHT = 600;

ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width/3, canvas.height)
ctx.fillRect((canvas.width/3 + canvas.width/3), 0, canvas.width/3, canvas.height)

ctx.fillStyle = '#2a2a2a';
ctx.fillRect(canvas.width/3, 0, canvas.width/3, canvas.height)

ctx.clearRect(0,0,500,600)
let Car = new car(GAME_WIDTH, GAME_HEIGHT);
Car.draw(ctx);
```

**car.js**

```
export default class car{
    constructor(gamewidth, gameheight){

        this.width = 100;
        this.height = 100;
        this.position = {
            x : gamewidth/2 - this.width/2,
            y : gameheight - this.height - 10,
        };
    }

    draw(ctx){
        ctx.fillStyle = '#ff6969';
        ctx.fillRect(this.position.x, this.position.y, this.width, this.height);
    }

}
```

I'm getting the following errors in my logs

```
firstgame.html:1 Access to script at 'file:///C:/MY%20DATA/java%20projects/cargame/index.js' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.
```

error 2

```
firstgame.html:19 GET file:///C:/MY%20DATA/java%20projects/cargame/index.js net::ERR_FAILED
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to put your project inside any local server such as XAMP,MAMP,WAMP and add '.js' to the car import in index.js file, run your local server and it will work.

[image: Check the output]

Comment: How do i use a local server such as the names you provided? The tutorial I was following used codesandox.io and it was running fine, but when I tried it there its giving me errors saying, could not find module in path

Comment: https://www.ionos.com/digitalguide/server/tools/xampp-tutorial-create-your-own-local-test-server/.   Check this out you will get to know how to install xamp, after installation put your project in htdocs folder where xamp is installed

Answer (score 1):

you need to add type="module" to the script tag

```html
<script type="module" src='index.js'></script>
```

and the fix the import

```js
import car from "./car.js";
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it doesn't seem to be helping. My canvas is still blank.

Comment: try to add .js in the import

Comment: I actually just starting learning javascript, I'm following a tutorial but I don't know what I'm doing wrong. How do I check the console logs?

Comment: right click (the mouse), select inspect or inspect elements (depends on your browser), on top of the opened screen you'll find sort of a nav bar select console

Comment: I'm getting 2 errors, I have added them to my question

Comment: the probleme is that you are trying to acces the html file directlly via file:// protocol which causes a Cross Origin Access problemes, try to use a server to serve you static file, if you are using npm you can use this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve